how do I get an element value from a pivot chart in excel by clicking on the element
I am struggling to find a way to get the value of element UQZCJQJPVL in the chart by clicking on it in VB.
image of the chart here: pivotchart
I found that this code is able to get all the parts of the label that match the regex if I switch to a sheet that has a pivotchart. Now how do I get that value by clicking on it ?
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim seriesCollection As seriesCollection
    Dim series As series
    Dim point As point
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim match As Object

    ' Create RegExp object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = "[A-Z0-9]{10}" ' Defines the regex pattern

    ' Iterates all charts in the active sheet
    For Each cht In Sh.ChartObjects
        Debug.Print "Chart data: " & cht.Name

        ' Get series collection of the chart
        Set seriesCollection = cht.Chart.seriesCollection

        ' iterates all series
        For Each series In seriesCollection
            Debug.Print "Series: " & series.Name

            ' Print category values that satisfy the specific format
            If Not IsEmpty(series.XValues) Then
                For i = 1 To series.Points.Count
                    ' Check if the category label has the specific format using regex
                    Set match = regex.Execute(series.XValues(i))
                    If match.Count > 0 Then
                        Debug.Print "Category value of point " & i & ": " & match(0)
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next series

        Debug.Print vbCrLf
    Next cht
End Sub


I tried with some events for charts like BeforeDoubleClick , MouseDown to no avail.

Have a look here maybe: https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/

Doesn’t work . That guy is associating code to charts directly. I have pivot charts . Nothing works

It works the same on pivot charts as on regular charts. I just tested to be sure.

@JonPeltier sorry but it doesn’t . Pivot charts don’t have events. Please share your code

@ChrisNuvoli In fact it does work on a pivot chart. I tested it specifically. Pivot Charts (and Pivot Tables by the way) have events. The code is in https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel. But I just uploaded a zip file with the workbook with regular and pivot charts here: ChartEvents.zip.

@JonPeltier Yes but there is no way to click on a label on x-axis and get the data associated to the point in the values of the collection. Excel sees those elements as xlaxis . This is ridiculous.

@ChrisNuvoli Click on the point, and get the series number i and point number j. Parse the ith series formula, extract the X and Y values, get the X and Y value for the jth point. My sample file does exactly that.

@JonPeltier please check the picture I added to the original post. I am clicking on that ID Ticket. That point is seen as element 21 xlaxis. Non as series.

If you are clicking where the tooltip is, you are clicking on the axis. Clicking on the axis can tell you about the axis, not about the point. Clicking on the point can tell you about the point.

@JonPeltier ok but how comes the axis has that data and you can’t access by selecting ? When you click on the id it’s recognized by excel itself. Yet you can’t get it

No data in stored with the axis. Mouse over an axis, the tooltip only shows you which axis it is. Click on the axis, VBA's GetChartElement gives you the ElementID (21 for xlAxis), Arg1 for axis type (xlCategory, xlValue, xlSeries), and Arg2 for xlPrimary or xlSecondary; again, this only defines which axis it is. Data resides in each series, my sample file shows how to parse series formulas to extract this data. In the Select Data Source dialog, you can assign category axis labels to the axis; these are not stored with the axis, they are stored in each series formula. This is How Excel Works.
